# Variable defined in function not callable by another function? Jython

Tags: python, function, jython

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this code. I have to follow guidelines for this class so they want it so your weekly pay is calculated by a "calc_weekly_wages" function and then for a "main" function to call the other and print it in a sentence rather than just a number output. I get an error that my "finalPay" variable is not defined, can anyone help?

```
hoursWorked = requestInteger("Enter weekly hours worked")
hourlyWage = requestNumber("Enter your hourly wage")

def calc_weekly_wages():
  if hoursWorked <= 40:
    finalPay = hoursWorked * hourlyWage
    return (finalPay)
  elif hoursWorked > 40:
    finalPay = 40 * hourlyWage + (hoursWorked - 40)*(hourlyWage * 1.5)
    return finalPay

def main():
  calc_weekly_wages()
  print ("Wages for " + str(hoursWorked) + "at $" + str(hourlyWage) + "is " + str(finalPay))

main()
```

Comment: You need to store the value returned by `calc_weekly_wages()`, e.g. `finalPayOutput = calc_weekly_wages()`. Then in your print statement, call that variable instead: `"is " + str(finalPayOutput))`. Alternately you could define `finalPay` as a field at the top as you have with `hoursWorked`: `finalPay = calc_weekly_wages()`

Comment: oh jeez im stupid, thanks man, it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `finalPay` is indeed out of scope on the line that does the `print`.  The local variables of a function are inaccessible outside of that function.

Fortunately, `finalPay` is returned by `calc_weekly_wages()`.  So, you could capture the return value in a variable by the same name:

```
finalPay = calc_weekly_wages()
```

That would fix things.  Or you could substitute the problematic reference to `finalPay` with the call to your function:

```
print ("Wages for " + str(hoursWorked) + "at $" + str(hourlyWage) + "is " + str(calc_weekly_wages()))
```

And that would work too.